# Categorizing database rows based on column values

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, case, categories

I have database table "tbl_data" with 2 columns - col1 and col2 data where I need to compute (col1/col2) for each of the rows. 
Use this result to categorize each data row into following categories:

```
Category1: top 10% 
Category2: 20-30%
Category3: 30-40% 
. . . 
. . .
Category10: 90-100%....
```

(here I do not know the max value of col1/col2 which would ideally be the 100%)
Could you please let know how to articulate this using SQL query? I am using MySQL

At the end I would like to display the records based on the bucket (10%, 10-20%, 20-30%.. so on)
I grouped to.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.

```
select 
  CASE 
    WHEN col1/col2 < 0.2 THEN '20%'
    WHEN col1/col2 < 0.4 THEN '40%'
    WHEN col1/col2 < 0.6 THEN '60%'
    WHEN col1/col2 < 0.8 THEN '80%'
    ELSE '100%'
  END as category
from tbl_data
```

The problem is that I'm not sure what you mean by you don't know the max value of col1/col2.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b23d/3)

Based on the comment, something like this might work, where the maximum is normalized:

```
select 
  CASE 
    WHEN col1/col2 < max_value * 0.2 THEN '20%'
    WHEN col1/col2 < max_value * 0.4 THEN '40%'
    WHEN col1/col2 < max_value * 0.6 THEN '60%'
    WHEN col1/col2 < max_value * 0.8 THEN '80%'
    ELSE '100%'
  END as category
from tbl_data
  join (select max(col1/col2) as max_value
          from tbl_data) as max_val
```

[SQL Fiddle for case number 2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3aeb6/1)

Comment: I meant that max(col1/col2) is not known and it has to be computed in the SQL => it's like [(col1/col2) / max(col1/col2)] >0 and <0.1, then I categorize this into 10% bucket.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to enumerate the ratio into deciles.  Perhaps this does what you want:

```
select d.*, 1 + floor(10*(rank - 1) / @r) as decile
from (select d.*, (@r := @r + 1) as rank
      from tbl_data d cross join
           (select @r := 0) vars
      order by col1 / col2
     ) d
```

Comment: But I get the result as all the table rows are grouped in decile1 only. Not able to get decile2, decile3 and so on...